# How Marketing Cloud handles Leads converting to Contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sales-cloud

According to [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000357940&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1) Knowledge Article

> When you then convert the Lead to a Contact, the values change and the ContactID replaces the LeadID and this then update All Contacts (view in Contact Builder) too, to ensure the record transitions smoothly.

The questions are:
Does ContactID replace the LeadID in Synchronized DE Lead_Salesforce? Which field is being updated in All Contacts (ContactKey?) If so, is SubscriberKey from All Subscriber list being updated?

Please provide more details about the behavior of converted Lead in synchronized DEs, All Contacts, and All Subscribers lists. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce doesn't remove converted Leads, so they will be retained in the synchronized DE indefinitely. Once converted to a Contact, you'll have both the converted Lead and Contact records syncing into synchronized data extensions. This unfortunately leads to duplication that's hard to avoid and counts toward your contact limit, from a billing perspective.

To mitigate this, you could choose to only sync Leads that haven't converted into Marketing Cloud, and then delete Marketing Cloud contacts associated with those converted Leads. But then you lose tracking data related to those Leads. It's a real shame there's no way to merge the two contacts.

Most important is to ensure you're carrying the subscription status over to the new contact, not just for email but for all channels.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. And if I use Contact Deletion Function and remove converted Leads from All Contacts (and don't remove them from Synscronized Lead_Salesforce DE), then the process adds a new contact record in All Contacts with an 8-4-4-4-12 character UUID? As described in https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_implement_synchronized_data_sources_best_practices.htm&type=5